# Stop converting md5 value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, passwords, md5, database-migration

While migrating the data from one DB to another, inserting in password column (MD5), we actually want to prevent converting it to MD5.

A normal query remains the same and it's fine.

While migrating I don't want to convert the value to md5 since it is already a md5 value in another DB.

Any pointer in this ? I don't mind if I required to change my query.

Inshort, I just want to skip the md5 process while migrating. Just want to place it as a normal value.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. Do you want to retrieve the original password from an MD5 hash?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Nope. I just migrating password value from one DB to another. While inserting in DB the already MD5 value again converting to MD5. Want to prevent that.

Comment: You're assuming that MySQL scans for column names (or something like that) and, whenever it finds one that's called "password", it creates a MD5 hash. Such feature does not exist. It wouldn't make sense at several levels. If you get a hash, your custom code is responsible for it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I'm inserting values through a stored procedure. Is it possible to stop doing at that level ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably not explaining myself properly. It's **your** code what's creating the hash. Wherever you do it, just don't. For instance, if you have `INSERT INTO user (user_id, username, password) VALUES (:user_id, :username, MD5(:password))` replace `MD5(:password)` with `:password`.